# How do I assign a drawable to ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-resources, cyanogenmod

I am working on adding halo into cyanogenmod 11. And for that I am using a method which gets the state of halo being active or not, and then assigns image to it accordingly.

First, here's my code from latest try (I have made multiple attempts to do this task)->

```
protected void updateHalo() {
//mHaloActive is a boolean. mHaloButton is an ImageView
    mHaloActive = Settings.System.getInt(mContext.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.HALO_ACTIVE, 0) == 1;
    int resID;
    String mDrawableName;
    if (mHaloActive) {
        mDrawableName = "ic_notify_halo_pressed";
        resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        mHaloButton.setImageResource(resID);
    } else {
        mDrawableName = "ic_notify_halo_normal";
        resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        mHaloButton.setImageResource(resID);
    }
    if (mHaloActive) {
        if (mHalo == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mHalo = (Halo) inflater.inflate(R.layout.halo_trigger, null);
            mHalo.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = mHalo.getWMParams();
            mWindowManager.addView(mHalo, params);
            mHalo.setStatusBar(this);
        }
    } else {
        if (mHalo != null) {
            mHalo.cleanUp();
            mWindowManager.removeView(mHalo);
            mHalo = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now here, it says `cannot find symbol: method getPackageName()`

Earlier I had made multiple attempts too like using `setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_notify_halo_pressed);`
But that was giving me NPE.

Then I also tried using:

```
Resources resources = getResources();        mHaloButton.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_notify_halo_pressed));
```

But this gave error `cannot find symbol: method getResources()`

And I also tried `mHaloButton.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.ic_notify_halo_pressed);` but it gives error: `setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) in android.widget.ImageView cannot be applied to (int)`

So I know it needs resource ID, but how do I get that?

Please note: I am not building an application, and this is not a android studio project. I am trying to port halo to cyanogenmod 11.

Comment: Convert into bitmap and then apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `Resources resources = getResources();` with `Resources resources = mContext.getResources();` since you have already a reference to Context.

Same for `getPackageName()`. Replace it with `mContext.getPackageName()`.